# Get comma separated value to multiple rows in informatica?

Tags: informatica, scenarios

I have 2 cols

```
SID  CID
1    101,102
2    201,2021,231
```

IN TGT

```
SID CID
1   101
1   102
2   201
2   2021
2   231
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use normalizer.
First after SQ, use expression transformation to split CID column.

```
o_cid1= substr(cid,1,3) --if length is variable you need to use instr
o_cid2= substr(cid,instr(cid,',',1)+1, 3) -- if length is variable you need to use instr
...
```

Then use normalizer. Properties should be

Number of occurrences of sid =0
Number of occurrences of cid =3

You will see 4input ports(3for for cid1,2,3 and 1for sid) and two outports(1cid,1sid) related to your needs.

Conect sid, o_cid1,o_cid2... To corresponding ports.

Finally connect output ports cid,sid to target.